# Google map Info box doesn't listen the click event

Tags: jquery, google-maps-api-3

How to attach a click event to a goole map

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create marker & add a listener to it.

```
amarker = new google.maps.Marker(
           { position: alocations,
             map: map,
             title: "title " 
           } );
        google.maps.event.addListener(amarker, 'click', 
            function() {
              markerClick(this);
            }
        );
    }
    function markerClick( mark )
    {
       //do something
    }
```

You can follow the link for more details
http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/events.html